# Verifying I Played Pocket 3s Fine

Tags: betting-strategy

### Starting Info

- Hero: 33
- Position: Cut-Off
- Stakes: 0.50/1.00
- Stack: 35.00
- Cash Game NLHE

---

### Pre-Flop action

- Hero raises to 2.00 (2BB)
- Button calls (100 behind)
- Small blind folds
- Big blind calls (80 behind)
- Pot: ~ 6.50

---

### Flop

- J, 5, 2
- BB checks
- Hero bets $2.50 or so
- Button calls
- BB calls
- Pot: ~ 12.50

---

### Turn

- 3 (making my set)
- BB checks
- I bet pot (12.00)
- Dealer calls
- BB re-raises, putting me all-in
- I call
- Button folds
- BB shows A4o for the straight

---

### River

- 8

---

Just checking for any leaks or things I should be considering that I may not have. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts here

1. Why are you sitting in 100NL with only 35? Never do that
2. I like a bigger PF raise, 3x at a bare minimum and don't be shy about going higher than that

As played, it's hard to avoid going broke here because of the beauty of a set. So, I think you played it fine in the sense that many people can't find a fold here - myself included - but there are still things to tighten up in your game.

A4 got into the pot by getting 5.5-1 odds, that's probably not a mistake on their part and you allowed it to happen with the small PF sizing.

Comment: Thx. Can you elaborate on this: `Why are you sitting in 100NL with only 35? Never do that`. What do you do if you buy in 100 (or 200) and draw down... when do you re-buy?

Comment: @ScottSkiles I rebuy any time that I am below 100BB. This is easy online because you can set the rebuy settings for this. But in live play, it requires you to buy two stacks at the start of each session, one of which goes in your pocket for rebuys. You should always be optimistic that you are about to play your best hand ever and be ready to capitalize on it with a big stack ready to go! :)

Comment: @ScottSkiles You shouldn't be playing such high stakes if you can't afford to play 100 or 200bb. You can play profitable poker sure, but you're missing out a lot of value by winning heaps when you make the nuts but you don't have enough money to match the villain's stack.